# memory error using valgrind, strcpy

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, strcpy

I've been using valgrind, but for some reason I keep getting a memory error using a simple string copy with two strings that are the same size, in C.

The Code effected is:

```
node->entry = (char*)malloc(strlen(string)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(node->entry, string);
```

With string being: char* string = "Hello There".
The Error is:
Invalid write of size 2

```
==2035==    at 0xD494: memmove$VARIANT$sse42 (mc_replace_strmem.c:987)
==2035==    by 0x100001793: __inline_strcpy_chk (_string.h:94)
==2035==    by 0x100001699: createList (main.c:10)
==2035==    by 0x100001BE6: main (main.c:132)
==2035==  Address 0x10000c0fa is 10 bytes inside a block of size 11 alloc'd
==2035==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==2035==    by 0x100001635: createList (main.c:9)
==2035==    by 0x100001BE6: main (main.c:132)
```

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: So much noise in your code. It should be `node->entry = malloc(strlen(string) + 1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
malloc(strlen(string)*sizeof(char));
```

You are not taking the ending `'\0'` into account. So it should have been `(strlen(string) + 1)`.

---

Side note:

```
type *x;
x = malloc(size * sizeof(*x))
```

is much more maintainable than

```
type *x;
x = (type *)malloc(size * sizeof(type));
```

because you don't repeat yourself 3 times.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is broken:

1. You need to allocate space for the string termination character, failure to do so will make `strcpy()` write into non-allocated memory and cause a buffer overflow bug.
2. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169)
3. You need to check that the allocation succeeds before writing to the memory.

Further, note that `sizeof (char)` is always 1, so there's no need to involve it. Just use:

```
node->entry = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
```

Or, check if you have `strdup()` since it combines all of the above.

In the general case, as @Shahbaz noted, it's better to use the `sizeof` operator on the result of dereferencing the left-hand pointer, to avoid repeating the type name:

```
type *x;
x = malloc(amount * sizeof *x);
```

Also, note that `sizeof` is not a function, the parenthesis are only needed when the argument is a type name and that case, as I just argued, is to be avoided.